# Do I need to manually redeem Games with Gold titles, or are they automatically added to my library?

Tags: xbox-network

I have a subscription to Xbox Live, prepaid through some time next year. So far, I've been downloading each [Games with Gold](https://www.xbox.com/en-CA/live/gold#gameswithgold) title as they've become available, to try them out and to make sure they're added to my library. However, I'm not sure whether that's actually necessary.

I will be traveling for a couple of months and won't be able to access my console. Will I miss out on the Games with Gold titles for the time I'm away, or are they automatically added to my games library even if I don't install them, so they'll be waiting when I get back?

Comment: Apparently Xbox One Games with Gold titles are only playable while your subscription is active, and become inaccessible otherwise. 360 games remain accessible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they won't be added automatically. You'll have to redeem them to add them to your account.

I'm not entirely certain as for the reason behind this, but I heard it's to avoid complaints if some people were to receive games they wouldn't want in their library.

**However, you do not need access to your console to redeem the games.** If you have a Windows 10 laptop, you can use the built-in *Xbox Console Companion* app (formerly "*Xbox*") to redeem the games without access to your Xbox. Simply access the *Microsoft Store* from within the app and redeem the games from there. Note: Do not use the Microsoft Store app directly, or else finding the games will be much harder.

Alternatively, you can redeem the games on any computer with internet access on: https://www.xbox.com/en-US/live/gold?xr=shellnav#gameswithgold

Simply select the game you want to redeem. The site should redirect you to the proper region, according to the account you're currently logged in as.